# subscript out of range error within array for loop in vba

Tags: vba, excel, range, unique

Making a copy of data from a reference file and making the copy unique and then placing those unique texts in a loop of column headers in a new sheet. Anybody know why im getting the error "subscript out of range" within the "With wsDB" line?

```
 Sub uniqueyes()

Dim wsRef As Worksheet
Dim wsDB As Worksheet

Set wsRef = Worksheets("reference1")
Set wsDB = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wsRef
    .Range("F1:F60").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("I1"), unique:=True

    Dim arrValues As Variant
    arrValues = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

End With

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, 4) = "Title" Then

        For j = 1 To (UBound(arrValues)) Step 1


         With wsDB

          .Range(.Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(i, j * 4 + 4)).Value = arrValues(j)



            End With

        Next j

    End If

Next i

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load the values in the array likes this:
`arrValues = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`
it becomes multidimensional. ( Rows and Columns )

In this line you are just providing one dimension(row) as `j` and missing the other dimension (column). Hence the error.

`.Range(.Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), .Cells(i, j * 4 + 4)).Value = arrValues(j)`

Comment: okay but when I try to add a column, it gives me other errors